# Need to inject values from parent object into child object when serializing

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm setting up an API which dynamically advertises services as part of its response, letting the consumer know what else they can do with the object. I can't work out how to inject the parent's objects type and ID into the service URI.

I'm using attributes and custom JSON.NET IValueProviders to create the URIs (which is working fine for other dynamic examples), but in this case I need a property from outside the object.

Classes looks similar to:

```cs
public class Person
{
public Guid ID { get; set; }
public string Type { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
[ObjectUri]
public string Uri { get; set; }

...

public IEnumerable<Service> Services { get; set; }
}

public class Service 
{
public string ServiceName { get; set; }

[ServiceUri]
public string ServiceUri { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using a custom contract resolver to add the custom IValueProvider (ObjectUriValueProvider) which renders the object URI (which is obviously just using information from the same object).

However, because the contract resolver is operating at the level of the abstract model, there's no way to pass concrete values pertaining to the parent object to ServiceUriValueProvider.

Ideal output:

```
{
"id": "ae330dc8-0217-4c58-b64b-44a1c7ba4f46",
"type": "Person",
"name": "Fred",
"uri": "https://server/api/person/ae330dc8-0217-4c58-b64b-44a1c7ba4f46"
...
"services": [
 {
"serviceName": "ListNotes",
"serviceUri": "https://server/api/notes/person/ae330dc8-0217-4c58-b64b-44a1c7ba4f46"
},
{
"serviceName": "ListContactDetails",
"serviceUri": "https://server/api/contacts/person/ae330dc8-0217-4c58-b64b-44a1c7ba4f46"
}
]
}
```

The actual results at the moment don't include the type and id being correctly populated into

```
{
"services": [
 {
"serviceName": "ListNotes",
"serviceUri": "https://server/api/notes/{type}/{id}"
},{
"serviceName": "ListContactDetails",
"serviceUri": "https://server/api/contacts/{type}/{id}"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Can you include your custom ContractResolver / ValueProvider and the code you are using to serialize so that we can reproduce what you are doing?

Comment: Hi Brian, I can but I ended up going a slightly different route using middleware to modify the response in flight.